# Symfony2: fetching data from database returns a "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I moved a project to a hosted webspace (at all-inkl, de) which worked well on my local computer. It's possible to access the project at intern.wir-sind-kirche.de and to successfully login. If I click onto a menuitem after logging in this results in a "500 Internal Server Error". It happens during this call:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('LFToolsCRMBundle:Mailinglist')->findAll();
```

which is placed in an action to show all stored data of the named entity in a table.

It looks as if the database is ok as far as I'm able to login.

Both versions of the project, on my local computer and at the webspace as well are completly identical.

Thanks for any help and hints.

Comment: Test it using dev environment (access site via app_dev.php instead of app.php). In that case you will see what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: @Hast, I did what you suggested, now getting a better response: "[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\index" in class LFTools\CRMBundle\Entity\Mailinglist does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded." I wonder why because on my local system the error does not appear and local and web hosting are absolutly the same files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using absolute annotation name, import `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` namespace as `ORM` and then use `@ORM\Index`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM

// ...
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Index(...)
     */
    public $someProperty;
}
```

**Note also** that annotations are case-sensitive, so there is no `@ORM\index`, it is `@ORM\Index`.

You could have different behavior on various machines because of different php or bundles versions.

Comment: Got it, the little difference in "identical" files between Windows and Unix is distinguishing in upper and lower case, puhhh.

Comment: If my answer solves your issue, accept it to help other people with the same problem searching for correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is often a permission problem on the app/cache and/or app/log folders. But when developing you should always use /web/app_dev.php it has great debug tools and will tell you explicitly what the problem is instead of throwing a 500 error. Additionally you should read the documentation available here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/index.html